How to fix my contact form to be clickable when in mobile mode
I am having issues clicking on my form fields when in mobile view. I'm only able to click on my message portion where I can input text. When I click any of the other fields, it acts like a link from my navbar and takes me to that particular section. I removed most of my content on my website for simplicity sake. I am posting my code below
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Jake Monroe Website</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

    <!--box icons-->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body style="background: black">
    <!--header design-->
    <header class="header">
        <a href="#" class="logo"> Jake Monroe</a>

        <div class='bx bx-menu' id="menu-icon"></div>

        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#education">Education</a>
            <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

            <span class="active-nav"></span>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!--home section design-->
    <section class="home" id="home">
            <div class="home-content">    
                <h1>Hi, I'm <span>Jake Monroe</span></h1>
                <div class="text-animate">
                    <h3>Analyst</h3>
                </div>
                    <p style="color:white">Looking to work with ambitious individuals in the Finance and Energy Sectors to help build a sustainable world</p>            
                <div class="btn-box">
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Hire Me</a>
                    <a onclick="tab.open('','page','location=0,toolbar=0,...')"
                    href="#" target="page" class="btn">Resume</a>
                </div>
                <div class="home-sci">
                    <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-linkedin-square' ></i></a>
                </div>
        </div>   
         
    </section>
    


<!-- contact section design -->
<script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false</script>
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" name="hiddenThankYou" id="hiddenThankYou" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted){window.location='Thankyou.html';}"></iframe>
<section class="contact" id="contact" style="background-color: black">
    <h2 class="heading">Contact <span>Me!</span></h2>
       
    <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/" method="POST" target="hiddenThankYou" onsubmit="submitted=true">
        <div class="input-box">
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="entry.100"></label>
                <input type="text" name="entry.50" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                <span class="focus"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="entry.90"></label>
                <input name="entry.90" type="email" id="email" pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                <span class="focus"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <div class="input-field">
                    <label for="entry.50"></label>
                    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="entry.50" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                    <span class="focus"></span>
                </div>
            
                <div class="input-field">
                <label for="entry.20"></label>
                <input type="text" name="entry.20" placeholder="Email Subject" required>
                <span class="focus"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="textarea-field">
                <label for="entry.20"></label>
                <textarea id="" cols="30" rows="10" name="entry.20" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
                <span class="focus"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-box btns">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
            
    </form>
</section>
    <script src="/NewWebsite/script.js"></script>
</body>


</html>

.navbar a {
    font-size: 1.7rem; 
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left: 3.5rem;
    transition: .3s;
    padding: 100px 100px 100px;
}

.navbar a:hover{
    color: var(--main-color);
    transition:.1s;
}

.navbar a.active{
    color: var(--main-color);
    transition: .1s;
}

#menu-icon {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    color: var(--text-color);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}


.contact{
    min-height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 7rem;
}

.contact form{
    max-width: 70rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 120px 20px 20px; /* top sides bottom */
}

.contact form .input-box {
    position: relative; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contact form .input-box .input-field{
    position: relative;
    width: 49%;
    margin: .8rem 0;
}

.contact form .input-box .input-field input,
.contact form .textarea-field textarea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: var(--text-color);
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: .6rem;
    border: .2rem solid var(--main-color);
    z-index: -10;
}

.contact form .input-box .input-field input::placeholder,
.contact form .textarea-field textarea::placeholder{
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.contact form .focus {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--second-bg-color);
    border-radius: .6rem;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: .5s;   
}

.contact form .input-box .input-field input:focus~.focus,
.contact form .input-box .input-field input:valid~.focus,
.contact form .textarea-field textarea:focus~.focus,
.contact form .textarea-field textarea:valid~.focus{
    width: 100%;
}


.contact form .textarea-field {
    position: relative;
    margin: .8rem 0 2.7rem;
    display: flex;
}

.contact form .textarea-field textarea{
    resize: none;
}

.contact form .btn-box.btns .btn{
    cursor:pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
  
    #menu-icon{
        display: block;
    }
    
    section{
        padding: none;
    }
    .navbar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1rem 4% !important;
        z-index: -1;
        transition: .25s ease;
        transition-delay: .25s;
    }
    
    .navbar.active{
        left:0;
        transition-delay: 0s;
        
    }

    .navbar .active-nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: -100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: var(--bg-color);
        border-top: .1rem solid rgba( 0, 0, 0, .2);
        z-index: -1;
        transition: .25s ease;
        transition-delay: 0s;
        
    }

    .navbar.active .active-nav{
        left:0;
        transition-delay: .25s;
    }

    .navbar a {
        display: block;
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin: 3rem 0;
        transform: translateX(-20rem);
        transition: .25s ease;
        transition-delay: 0s;
    }

    .navbar.active a{
        transform: translateX(0);
        transition-delay: .25s;
    }

}


//Toggle icon navbar
let menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
let navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

menuIcon.onclick = () => {
    menuIcon.classList.toggle('bx-x');
    navbar.classList.toggle('active');
}
//Scroll Sections
let sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('header nav a');

window.onscroll = () => {
    sections.forEach(sec => {
        let top = window.scrollY;
        let offset = sec.offsetTop - 100;
        let height = sec.offsetHeight;
        let id = sec.getAttribute('id');

        if(top >= offset && top < offset + height) {
            //active navbar links
            navLinks.forEach(links => {
                links.classList.remove('active');
                document.querySelector('header nav a[href*=' + id + ']').classList.add('active');
            });
        }
    });
    //sticky header
    let header = document.querySelector('header');

    header.classList.toggle('sticky', window.scrollY > 100);

    /* remove toggle icon and navbar when click navbar links (scroll) */
    menuIcon.classList.remove('bx-x');
    navbar.classList.remove('active');
    
}

function togglePopup(){
    document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active")
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    if(event.key === "Escape"){
document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
    }
});

closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const modal = button.closest('.modal')
      closeModal(modal)
    })
  })




If I cobble the above together into a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/13Lstko0/, it looks nowhere near like a "proper" website - so I'm guessing there is still some basic formatting missing? Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Thanks for the help, I ended up redoing my navbar and got it to work. I think there was an issue with my JS that had an overlay for my contact form.
